# Tornado - Execute request in Thread Pool

Tags: python, threadpool, tornado, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to execute the tornado requests in a Thread Pool and looking to execute the methods of RequestHandler such as initialize, prepare & finish, get/post all under a same thread from thread pool.

I've extended tornado.web.RequestHandler class and overridden methods initialize, prepare & on_finish. Just added print statements for now. I'm planning to initialize my db connection in initialize, check request headers in prepare and close and return db connection back to the pool in the on_finish method. I extended my Base Handler and used ThreadPoolExecutor for executing get/post methods. However the initialize, prepare & on_finish still run under the main thread. I want them to run under the thread from ThreadPoolExecutor. I couldn't figure out, if we have any way for that.

```
#   Base HTTP Request Handler overridden from tornado.web.RequestHandler
from tornado import web
import threading

class BaseTornadoHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self) -> None:
        print("Initialize -> :{}:".format(threading.get_ident()))

    def prepare(self):
        print("Prepare -> :{}:".format(threading.get_ident()))
        #print(self.request.headers)

    def on_finish(self) -> None:
        print("on_finish -> :{}:".format(threading.get_ident()))
        #print(self.request.headers)

class TornadoWebReqHandler(BaseTornadoHandler):
    _thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10, thread_name_prefix="Web_Req_")

    @run_on_executor(executor='_thread_pool')
    def get(self):
        try:
            reqArgDict = self.request.arguments
            aNum = reqArgDict.get('anum')[0].decode('utf-8')
            print("runOnThread -> :{}: -> :{}:".format(aNum, threading.get_ident()))
            i = 0
            while(True):
                print("runOnThread -> :{}:".format(aNum))
                i = i+1
                time.sleep(10)
                break
        except Exception as excObj:
            print("Exception in runOnThread -> :{}:".format(excObj))
            pass
        print("Going to Write to Client -> :{}:".format(threading.get_ident()))
        self.write("SUCCESS -> :{}:".format(threading.get_ident()))
```

Question:

1. How do i execute a request completely in a different thread from
   main(initialize, prepare, get/post & on_finish)
2. How do i pass values from prepare to get/post method
3. Is there any way to set ThreadPoolExecutor in Application Level for the tornado, instead of at each handler, there by executing the methods - initialize, prepare, get/post, etc of one request in one thread, different from main thread.

Note: I do not want each method to be executed under different thread, just all methods of a request under same thread.

Please do share your insights and solutions.

A sample run, showing initialize, prepare & on_finish on main thread and actual requests on different threads.

```
Initialize -> :140084615829312:
Initialize -> :140084615829312:
Prepare -> :140084615829312:
Prepare -> :140084615829312:
runOnThread -> :1001: -> :140084261811968:
runOnThread -> :1002: -> :140083998988032:
runOnThread -> :1001:
runOnThread -> :1002:
Going to Write to Client -> :140084261811968:
on_finish -> :140084615829312:
Going to Write to Client -> :140083998988032:
on_finish -> :140084615829312:
```

Comment: Threads are children of the main process. Tornado is a single threaded event-loop server, i.e. its code runs on the main process. The purpose of the threads in an async app is to run blocking code without affecting the main process. This technique works for any kind of project out there. So, why do you want to run each request in a separate thread?

Comment: I'm expecting each request will take a while(close to 200 milliseconds) and i'm also expecting concurrent connections of more than 3K. So I don't think a single thread is going to cut. And i want each of the requests to run in separate threads from a thread pool and leave Tornado main thread to listen for more incoming connections.